# Error in two approaches when finding the number of distinct integers between 100 and 1000

Tags: permutations, combinations

**My first approach**

there are 3 places **A B C** to be filled.

For the unit place **C** :-

There are 10 possible ways to fill it because possible outcomes equals 0 to 9.

For the tens place **B** :-

In order to be distinct number of ways to fill is 9.

For **A** :-

From 10 possible choices 0 is out of the equation and the two previous numbers so this leaves us with 7 ways. So Number of Ways = 630.

But there is a case when 0 is either in the middle of at **C** then only two numbers gets eliminated i.e. 0 and one more number because **B** AND **C** cannot repeat the same numbers.

After Finding that my answer was wrong I tried the same process in reverse order

**2nd Approach**

For **A**

0 is out of the equation so there are 9 ways to fill A.

For **B**

Now 0 is included so no of ways to fill = 9 again.

For **C**

Number of ways to fill = 8.

So total number of ways = 648 which is the right answer.

Why is this happening ? Am I repeating some numbers?

Comment: @MorganRodgers: Did you mean to write "overcounting"?

Comment: There are $901$ integers between $100$ and $1000$ inclusive.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I think the wording must be incorrect as the details of the question suggest that the digits rather than the numbers should be distinct.

Comment: Dear OP, are you sure that the problem is cominatorial in nature and does not simply ask what @YvesDaoust replied? I think the downvotes are due to this imprecision in formulation.

Comment: @String: the OP must fix his question. I always refuse to fill in the missing details, at the risk of wasting time.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: You are right! The fact that the post provided an attempted solution is what sparked my interest, but the title is very misleading and potentially undercuts all the efforts of both the OP and me.

Comment: yes, the digits are distinct. My bad I'm sorry @String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is in relation to the question suggested by the body of the OP rather than the title. Hence this post adresses the following problem:

> How many integers with all three digits being distinct from one another are there between $100$ and $1000$?

### Repair of 1st approach

If you start from **C** and progress, the trouble is that when you get to **A**, the number of available choices depends on the choices for the other two, namely if zero was included among **B**, **C**, you then have 8 choices for **A**.

To break that down:

- Your original approach correctly stated what amoutns to: Choose **C** freely among $0..9$, then choose **B** not equal to **C** from the same set. This gives us $10\cdot 9$.
- By excluding the digit $0$, we instead get $9\cdot 8$.
- Hence the cases including the digit $0$ must be $10\cdot 9-9\cdot 8=2\cdot 9$. For those, the number of cases for **A** should be 8 instead of 7.

This leads to the figure:
$$
9\cdot 8\cdot 7+2\cdot 9\cdot 8=9\cdot 9\cdot 8
$$
which is the same figure now as your second approach.

Comment: your answer was exactly what I asked for i.e. what was I missing in my first approach. Thank you very much for your help. I will take great care in formulating the questions precisely next time. Forgive me as this is my second question posting here and I'm new to this,